# Spooler dissapear on java Printing

Tags: java, printing, spooler

I want to print textfile from java, but the spooler disappeared. It works if i print it directly from notepad. (i also trying pdf and image but it didn't work from java)

i noticed that data type from java is RAW but data type from notepad is nt emf 1008

here is my code :

```
public void print(){
    String bon = "something to print"

    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:/printer/bon.txt"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    try {
        writer.write(bon);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
    FileInputStream textstream = null; 
    try { 
        textstream = new FileInputStream("D:/printer/bon.txt"); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ffne) { 
    } 
    if (textstream == null) { 
       return; 
    } 
    // Set the document type
    DocFlavor myFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    // Create a Doc
    Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(textstream, myFormat, null); 
    // Build a set of attributes
    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet(); 
    aset.add(new Copies(1)); 
    aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A5);

    // discover the printers that can print the format according to the
    // instructions in the attribute set
    PrintService services =
            PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    // Create a print job from one of the print services
    if (services!=null) { 
        System.out.println(services.getName());
        System.out.println(services.isDocFlavorSupported(myFormat));
        DocPrintJob job = services.createPrintJob(); 
        try { 

                job.print(myDoc, aset); 

                textstream.close();
        } catch (PrintException pe) {
            Logger.getLogger(pe.getMessage());
            System.out.println("error1");
        } catch (IOException ex) { 
            Logger.getLogger(Printing.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("printer tidak ada");
    }
}
```

Comment: don't silently swallow exceptions

Comment: noted, but it pass that point, the print job is showed for a moment and then dissapeared